# Reading sim card file structure

Tags: file, structure, sim-card

I investigated sim-card file structure, but it was very unexpected for me to see that a directory doesn't have a list of nested files ID. Just:

- Number of DFs which are a direct child of the current directory
- Number of EFs which are a direct child of the current directory
- ...

So, I don't know how can I read all files from sim-card if I don't know some file ID inside it.
For example I want to read all file ID from current directory DFMExE(0x5F3C), so I need to increment counter - from 0x4F00 to 0x4FFF. It can take quite much time, especially if I want to read all files from sim-card.

Is there mo effective way?

Answer (score 3):

So there are two kinds of files inside it:-

1. Standard files - These fiels are listed in the 3GPP or ETSI standards and all the DFs and EFs are known to mobile as mobile phone vendors also follow the same specs. For example to display the operator name files 0x6F46 is used, so mobile will selected this file under GSM DF and siplay the name, similarly SIM vendor will write the operator name inside this file.
2. Properiety files - These are used by the applets or native application to store some data, as these are used internally by the applcation hence you will neve know these.

Just think of this like in windows you know that all program files will go inside c:\Program files and system files unsder c:\Windows, because these are standard. Also I created one app and I am using d:\myapp\dummy\test.dll file. So now you want to check standard file you will go to C:windows and for properitely files either you will scan in manually or you will ask me, what is the location.

Well yes you have to scan all files. you can write a small java program using SmartCardIO lib and it will scan in few seconds.